# Python: How to use %%% when parsing text

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse the text in the ebooks at gutenberg.org to extract info about the books, for example, the title.

Every book on there has a line like this:

```
*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK THE ADVENTURES OF SHERLOCK HOLMES ***
```

I'd like to use some thing like this:

```
book_name=()
index = 0
for line in finalLines:
    index+=1
    if  "*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK "%%%"***" in line:
        print(index, line)
        book_name=%%%
```

but I'm obviously not doing it right.  Can someone show me how it's done??

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a regex, something like `\*\*\* START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK (.*) \*\*\*`. Learn more: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html http://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is the way to go:

```
import re

title_regex = re.compile(r'\*{3} START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK (.*?) \*{3}')

for index, line in enumerate(finalLines):
    match = title_regex.match(line)

    if match:
        book_name = match.group(1)
        print(index, book_name)
```

You can also parse it line-by-line:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt'
book = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lines = book.readlines()
book.close()

reached_start = False
metadata = {}

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('***'):
        if not reached_start:
            reached_start = True
        else:
            break

    if not reached_start and ':' in line:
        key, _, value = line.partition(':')
        metadata[key.lower()] = value
```

Comment: :( TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: @user2344772: Change `r'\*{3}` to `b'\*{3}` and give it a go.

Comment: @user2344772 where do the loines come from?  if you have bytes there, it is a different issue.

Comment: and the lines come from this:

Comment: the `b` is just a representation of the fact that it is a byte string and not a simple string.

Comment: import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt'
book = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lines = book.readlines()
book.close()

Comment: I see.  I'm trying to make it a string that I can show users, how do I get rid of that?

Comment: @Deivore: You don't need to worry about it. `print` it out and it's gone.

Comment: I did, that's how I can see it

Comment: @Deivore: It might be easier to get this information out of the `Title: ...` line.

Comment: That could be.  I'm trying to use the lines with the *** because those lines can also identify the end and beginning of the actual content of the book.

Comment: Using Title:... was the way to go.  Thanks a lot for your help to the both of you, Blender and Elazar!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution:

```
sp = line.split()
if sp[:7]+sp[-1:] == '*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK ***'.split():
    bookname = ' '.join(sp[7:-1])
```

A better solustion will use regular expression, as suggested.

If you are working with bytes, you should use `b'*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK ***'`, or use `bytes.decode(s)` for any byte string.

Your snippet (with the `urlopen()` part) might look like this:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as book:
    finalLines = book.readlines()

booktitle_pattern = '*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK ***'.split()
bookname = None
for index, line in enumerate(finalLines):
    sp = [bytes.decode(word) for word in line.split()]
    if sp[:7]+sp[-1:] == booktitle_pattern :
        bookname = ' '.join(sp[7:-1])
```

Comment: that code didn't really do it, i'm afraid.What do the numbers 7 and -1 represent?

Comment: Oh nvm i get it, it's split into words.  Still can't make it work, though

Comment: i'm confused, are you using booktitle and bookname for different things?  Sorry, I'm very new and this all quite confusing to me

Comment: @Deivore two things: (a) I tried to give it a better name. it's irrelevant that you are new; names should be clear. (b) I added a bit about using bytes instead of simple strings, since it seems like what happens in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt'
book = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
lines = book.readlines()
book.close()



import re

title_regex = re.compile(b'\*{3} START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK (.*?) \*{3}')

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    match = title_regex.match(line)

    if match:
        book_name = match.group(1)
        print(book_name)
```